# Are GitLab groups never public?

Tags: gitlab

It appears that GitLab.com `/groups/` don't appear to be public by default or at all (unless you're part of the group).

Is there a way to make them public?

If not, why does GitLab deviate from the rest of Gitorious, GitHub, BitBucket in this respect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there has to be at least one public project in the group in order for the group to be public. You can browse through public projects by visiting https://gitlab.com/explore/groups.

For example, https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org is public and you can see the landing page even you are not logged in.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere at all?

Comment: You are right this is not :/ I [submitted an MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/451), it should be merged soon and appear in next version. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: it would be nice if it's possible to also make it public if some repositories are shared with the group.  For example, there is no official git repository of NetBSD; however, a single NetBSD developer (currently "jsonn" on GitHub) may volunteer to create one under his own account, and share it with NetBSD.  Similarly, I'd like to share my http://mdoc.su/ with the NetBSD group.  Sharing is already possible on GitLab, but it would seem weird to have to create a public project for such sharing to be public.

Comment: I've filed an issue in regards to my last comment as above.  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1315